# Why doesn't my PPA show up on Launchpad?

Tags: ppa, application-development, launchpad, quickly

I'm trying to create a project with Quickly, and to make it available on Launchpad through a PPA. I created a PPA (`ppa:vetetix/quickgcal`) and a project page (`quickgcal`). I added code, shared it, released it, etc. Several packages are “available” on launchpad, but when I go to the PPA's location, I get a 404, as if the PPA hadn't been created.

My question is: did I do something wrong? Should I wait some more? Is there a bug on Launchpad which screwed my PPA?

- [Project page](https://launchpad.net/quickgcal)
- [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~vetetix/+archive/quickgcal)

Answer (score 4):

Your package is pending.

[image]

The build results are available [here](https://launchpad.net/~vetetix/+archive/quickgcal/+build/2848408) by clicking on the green gear. The package status there is ``awaiting publication`.